# How to access/highlight a polyline in Autodesk Viewer

Tags: javascript, autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Using Autodesk Forge Viewer

Two questions

First

> I have a converted DWG to SVF file. I want to be able to highlight a
>   polyline   like it does when you click on it with a mouse. Can anyone
>   give me pointers on how to do this. I can not figure out how to access
>   getMaterials.highlightObject2D if that is indeed what I am supposed to
>   use.

Second

> Assuming the first is possible.  Is there any way to see the DWGs
>   object_handles after the drawing is converted.  I want to "highlight"
>   specific polylines

Answer (score 0):

For #1, you can use [.select()](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/12/select-all-elements-in-the-viewer-with-view-and-data-api-with-javascript.html):

```
_viewer.select(dbIds);
```

or maybe can change the color like this:

```
function color(dbId, color) {
    var elementIds = [dbId];
    _viewer.setColorMaterial(elementIds, parseInt(color/*HEX COLOR*/, 16));
}
```

For #2, you can iterate through the properties like this:

```
function findProperty(dbId) {
    _viewer.model.getProperties(dbId, function (props) {
        props.properties.forEach(function (prop) {
            if (prop.displayName === 'Handle') {
                // do something
            }
        });
    });
}
```

But you'll need to iterate through all elements, [check this sample on how get all properties on the model](https://gist.github.com/augustogoncalves/74bcfeaa7d4841166150#file-autodesk-adn-viewing-extension-chart-rgraph-js-L220) (this sample creates a pie chart).